# Optical flow generated from cycles render is not proper

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, vector

Scene generated from Blender, and flow is given. As it can be seen the flow generated is not proper, it is in a zig-zag format.

I see the scene at and above horizon have more zig-zag. Can someone tell what is wrong here?

[image: Image[1]]
[image: Image[2]]
[image: Image[3]]
[image: Image[4]]

[Edit] : Additional scene/info.
Scene
[image: Image_1]
[image: Image_2]
Using the information in the article, I plotted the flow
Article:http://www.tobias-weis.de/groundtruth-data-for-computer-vision-with-blender/. 
The 2nd channel is R [x displacement]
The 1st channel is R [y displacement]

for(int r = 0;r < GT.rows;r++)
{

```
  for(int c = 0;c < GT.cols;c++){ 

    float length_orig = std::sqrt((True_vec_orig[2].at<float>(r, c)) * (True_vec_orig[2].at<float>(r, c)) + (True_vec_orig[1].at<float>(r, c))*(True_vec_orig[1].at<float>(r, c)));
    int length = std::min(50, (int)length_orig);

    cv::Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1.x = (x_offset) + c; pt1.y = (y_offset) + r;
    pt2.x = std::max(0, std::min(im_d.cols - 1, (int) ((x_offset) + c + True_vec_orig[2].at<float>(r, c) ) ) ); 
    pt2.y = std::max(0, std::min(im_d.rows - 1, (int) ((y_offset) + r + True_vec_orig[1].at<float>(r, c) ) ));                              
    cv::line(im_d, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar((int)color_mat.at<double>(length, 0), (int)color_mat.at<double>(length, 1), (int)color_mat.at<double>(length, 2)), 1, 8, 0);

}
```

}
[image: groundtruth]

Now, I have an algorithm that calculates flow on every alternate pixel to save space on hardware and mark invalid flow on the algorithm as -128
if (U_Mat.at(r, c) != -128 && V_Mat.at(r, c) != -128)
if(r % 2 == 0 && c % 2 == 0).
This is the following plot I get from my algorithm.
[image: algo_output]

And when I apply the same condition on blenders output, I get this
[image: blender_out]

Which seems wrong if you look closely at the walls. I changed the True_vec_orig[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKMwN.png).at(r, c) value to negative. And this is the plot I obtained.

[image: blender_out]

This is quite close to movement but still incorrect. The flows seem to be smaller in length. I am unable to understand how are the flows of blender is to be used?

And if I plot the flow completely with True_vec_orig[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKMwN.png).at(r, c) negative, this is the plot I get,
[image: blend_out]

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: How are you generating such optical flow?

Comment: I have generated speed images from vector render and then plotted the x and y values on the images itself. R channel has x information and g channel has y information.

Comment: *Motion Blur* turned on? If not, I think makes sense having that kind of straight images...

Comment: No motion blur isn't on.

Comment: How does that explain the zig-zag pattern on the pedestrian [one half of the image] and no flow on one of the frames?

Comment: Does it make a difference? Suggest provide more information and preferably any simple scene.

Comment: the post has been updated